# How do I Connect my Armatures?

Tags: rigging

I was trying to build a bear skeleton in blender but there are 2 root armatures. How do I fix this? If I try to merge them with ctrl j it does not work and if I try to merge them with alt m it does not work.

Comment: could you please tell a bit more about why it doesn't work?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you've selected both Armatures in object mode, and then go to Object > Join

[image: demonstration video]